# Error while Importing pyexcel-xlxs

Tags: python, flask

Hello I'm using pythonanywhere.com for my web app, and im finding a way to import pyexcel for me to use, but it seems like I cant do it, because of this error. Im new to web app dev. so please. I need yur help.

when i installed it by cloning it from github it did this:

:

```
    $ git clone http://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx.git
    $ cd pyexcel-xlsx
    $ python setup.py install
```

But i got an error here:

```
13:56 ~ $ git clone http://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx.git
Cloning into 'pyexcel-xlsx'...
remote: Counting objects: 808, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 808 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 801
Receiving objects: 100% (808/808), 167.27 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (473/473), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
13:56 ~ $ cd pyexcel-xlsx
13:57 ~/pyexcel-xlsx (master)$ python setup.py install
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-22208.write-test'
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.
For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:
  https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html
Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using PythonAnywhere's standard Python, and not building virtual environments (which are under your control) `setup.py` is trying to install into the system `site-packages` directory, where you only have read permissions. If you want to continue without virtual environments then create a directory in your own area and tell `setup.py` to install it there with the `--install-lib dirname` option.

Then set the `PYTHONPATH` shell environment variable to that directory with `export PYTHONPATH=dirname` so that the interpreter adds that directory to its module search path and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hello @holdenweb I followed your suggestion and installed it correctly, but i seem to have a different problem now.

 `import fileinput`
 `import csv`
    `from pyexcel_xlsx import get_data`
    `data = get_data("file.xlsx")`
    `import json`

the line `from pyexcel` gets a syntax error :(

Comment: `from pyexcel_xlsx import csv`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

@holdenweb's instructions are good, but an even quicker way is just to run this in a bash console:

```
pip2.7 install --user https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx/archive/master.zip
```

Comment: It worked but when i code. the code `from pyexcel_xlsx import get_data` is still syntax error. any ideas why? It was successfully installed yet this happens

Comment: I see you've opened another question on Stack Overflow about that, so I'll answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314087/pyexcel-xlsx-successfully-installed-but-importing-is-still-on-syntax-error