# Pyexcel_xlsx successfully installed but importing is still on syntax error

Tags: python, bash, github

I'm making a web application and it manipulates spreadsheet files, but when I import this pyexcel library, it gets a syntax error. But I successfully installed it. Any ideas how to fix this? Really need your help.

I installed pyexcel_xlsx by running this in a bash console:

```
pip2.7 install --user https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-xlsx/archive/master.zip
```

im using Pythonanywhere.

Comment: Could you give the details of the syntax error?

Comment: Just for clarity: I ran the same command on PythonAnywhere, then started Python 2.7 and did `from pyexcel_xlsx import get_data`, and I didn't get a syntax error.  So if you post the specific error you're getting, it would help.

Comment: ...and also -- is there a specific reason why you want to install from GitHub rather than just using `pip2.7 install --user pyexcel-xlsx`?

Answer (score 0):

That command ran fine on my Python 3 installation.  I bet that the zip you're pointing at requires V3, but you're trying to install on V2.